# How do delete a files that was just uploaded to server and is still locked by the server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

My system Uploads files to an IIS server and then i manipualate them and after finished doing every thing, i need to delete the original file, the problem is that the IIS "grabs" the file and i can't delete it, when i close the procces i can delete it manualy from the server, but until i close the procces i can't even do that...

I'm using:`File.Delete(Server.MapPath(OriginalFileVirtualPath));` to delete the file.

p.s. for now i'm using the .net server, not a full active IIS, but i don't think that the problem is over there...It even make some sence that when i upload a file to the sever, it won't let to delete it strate away, but i'm sure there is a work around...

10x :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you remember to close the file after you're done manipulating it?

If the file is still open when you try to delete it, it may fail.  (I'd have to double-check the docs).  But failing to close the file will certainly cause the symptom you're observing where IIS sees the file as locked until you shut down your application.

Comment: LOL, 10x, thought about it myself and don't worry, i allready gave myself a punch....i was so stupid, just had to close the resource...your right...10x :-)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to close the File Stream. After that you can use `File.Delete()` method.

Doing the manipulations inside `using () { }` block and doing deletion after using block is a good practice:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    // Manipulation stuff
}
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: Good idea, but the Flush and close are unnecessary as they are implicit in the Dispose()